# Functional alternative to caching known "answers"

Tags: haskell, caching

I think the best way to form this question is with an example...so, the actual reason I decided to ask about this is because of because of [Problem 55 on Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/problem=55). In the problem, it asks to find the number of Lychrel numbers below 10,000. In an imperative language, I would get the list of numbers leading up to the final palindrome, and push those numbers to a list outside of my function. I would then check each incoming number to see if it was a part of that list, and if so, simply stop the test and conclude that the number is NOT a Lychrel number. I would do the same thing with non-lychrel numbers and their preceding numbers.

I've done this before and it has worked out nicely. However, it seems like a big hassle to actually implement this in Haskell without adding a bunch of extra arguments to my functions to hold the predecessors, and an absolute parent function to hold all of the numbers that I need to store.

I'm just wondering if there is some kind of tool that I'm missing here, or if there are any standards as a way to do this? I've read that Haskell kind of "naturally caches" (for example, if I wanted to define odd numbers as `odds = filter odd [1..]`, I could refer to that whenever I wanted to, but it seems to get complicated when I need to dynamically add elements to a list.

Any suggestions on how to tackle this?

Thanks.

PS: I'm not asking for an answer to the Project Euler problem, I just want to get to know Haskell a bit better!

Comment: Suggestion: `Control.Monad.State` can handle the passing of caches for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [memoizing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). There are a number of ways to do this. One fairly simple way is with the [MemoTrie](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MemoTrie) package. Alternatively if you know your input domain is a bounded set of numbers (e.g. [0,10000)) you can create an Array where the values are the results of your computation, and then you can just index into the array with your input. The Array approach won't work for you though because, even though your input numbers are below 10,000, subsequent iterations can trivially grow larger than 10,000.

That said, when I solved Problem 55 in Haskell, I didn't bother doing any memoization whatsoever. It turned out to just be fast enough to run (up to) 50 iterations on all input numbers. In fact, running that right now takes 0.2s to complete on my machine.

Comment: Turns out my integer reversing function that doesn't do any type conversion was horribly inefficient. I fixed that and now the program runs under a second on my machine as well, with no memoization. This is a wonderful tool to have in the future though. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @BenjaminKovach: I've found that when I need to muck with the digits of a number, it tends to be faster to just convert to a string and map each char back to an int than it does to try and do the conversion manually. In my solution to Problem 55 my number reverse function is defined as `revint = read . reverse . show`. And similarly for palindrome testing I just use `show` to get a string and test that.